# SQL WHERE for a COUNT within a SELECT statement that has a GROUP BY

Tags: sql, select, count, group-by, where-clause

```
SELECT COUNT(pkNotification) AS caseTotal
,COUNT(fkCaseType) AS Suspected
, COUNT(fkCaseType) AS Confirmed
, Disease.Name 
FROM [Notification] 
INNER JOIN [Disease] ON Notification.fkDisease=Disease.pkDisease 
GROUP BY Disease.Name
```

That's my statement.  But I need the COUNT(fkCaseType) AS Suspected to only be when fkCaseType=1 and for Confirmed to be when fkcaseType=2.

The problem is where I did subqueries, I had issues with the group by.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN fkCaseType = 1 THEN 1 END) Suspected,
COUNT(CASE WHEN fkCaseType = 2 THEN 1 END) Confirmed
```

In the first statement when `fkCaseType = 1` - then returns `1` thus is counted by `COUNT`, `NULL` otherwise, which is skipped. For the second one - the same.